# Querying id's that have multiple status conditions

Tags: sql, subquery, impala

I have the following data in Impala:

| ID | STATUS | Date |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | date1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | b | date2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | c | date3 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | a | date4 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | c | date5 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | a | date6 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | b | date7 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | c | date8 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | x | date9 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

I'd like to construct a query that returns the ID's only if that ID has status (A or B or C) and status X. I also want to return the date for status X. I can't figure out a good way to do this. Would I need to join two sub queries with different status conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work..

```
    select distinct id, date
    from t1
    where status = 'x'
    and id in 
      (select id
       from t1
       where status in ('a','b','c')
       )
```

db-fiddle here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uHVNeriETsXkLPV5kiSC1z/0

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect and simple.